# To what precision can people calculate the energy levels of oxygen or iron atoms?

Tags: atomic-physics

For simple atoms like Hydrogen or Helium, the precision is very high now. But how about atoms like oxygen or even uranium? Could it be one in a million?

Comment: Certainly not 1 in a million. The issue is that the milti-electron wave equation cannot be solved (even with a numerical approach) and some type of mean field approximation must be made (Hartree-Fock, etc).  These introduce errors (generally of a few %).  As the size of the atom increases, relativistic efffects become important and more errors are introduced by their approximate treatment.